# Getting the location of the Mobile device that is own location

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I am trying to get my own location.Below is the code which is giving me some error. Log Cat is given below.. Please help
And also want to know in which variable the Latitude and Longitude are stored.

MyLocation.java

```
public class MyLocation extends Activity{ 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  setContentView(R.layout.main); 

  /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */ 
  LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

  LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(); 
  mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener); 
} 

/* Class My Location Listener */ 
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{ 

  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
  { 

    loc.getLatitude(); 
    loc.getLongitude(); 

    String Text = "My current location is: " + 
    "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() + 
    "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude(); 

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  } 

  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
  { 
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); 
  } 

  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
  { 
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  } 

  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
  { 

  } 
} 
}
```

Log Cat

```
04-23 16:41:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3250): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{your.meh.namespace/your.meh.namespace.PostActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: your.meh.namespace.PostActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@458a8ad8
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: your.meh.namespace.PostActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@458a8ad8
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
04-23 16:41:27.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     ... 11 more
04-23 16:41:28.010: E/SemcCheckin(3250): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
04-23 16:41:28.040: I/dalvikvm(3250): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-23 16:41:28.100: I/dalvikvm(3250): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error (according to the stacktrace you pasted) has nothing to do with location issues.

The class PostActivity is not found which causes the ClassNotFoundException.

I think you have not pasted the code which actually fails

Comment: ohk... and in which variable the latitude and longitude is stored..?

Comment: I want then to be sent to a server... how do i do that..?

Comment: it's a completly different task, you should open a new question for it. Additionnaly, it's something that has been done and done multiple times so it's well documented, you will find many tutorials. Check for how to make a post (or get) http request to a server.

Comment: For that i need to get my current location and then post it... so first i need to get my own location first...

Comment: Your location is here : loc.getLatitude(); 
    loc.getLongitude(); 

    String Text = "My current location is: " + 
    "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() + 
    "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

if you need to know the street name or any postal information you should check the geocoder service : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html